# In Google Analytics, how can I determine the value of a page if no goals or revenue have been determined?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 4 years of data in Analytics with over 20 million pageviews for the entire site. No goals have ever been set up, and while the site is an ecommerce site, no ecommerce features in Google Analytics have ever been taken advantage of. So I have no way to determine what the actual value of a page is.

I've been tasked with determining if a particular page on the site is worth keeping around. How might I use all standard data (pageviews, bounce rate, time on page, time on site, etc.) to help determine the value of this page?

I really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: I think this is probably better off on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 3):

You say its an ecommerce website, so I assume you are interested in revenue as a KPI.

You don't actually need a Goal setup to measure goals if they are based on page URLs, so if for example you have a /thank-you page after a user has transacted, you could use the Top Content report to filter down to those pages, and the number of PageViews will be the equivalent to transactions.

If you know the total website revenue per month, you could then work out an average value per transaction, to get a rough idea on value per month.

Once you have that, you could move to channel analysis - segment the pageviews of /thank-you pageviews per medium.  Using your average value from above you can then attribute an approximate revenue each channel created for you.

Another tactic could be to segment to sessions that included your /thank-you page (or another page you think represents a valuable visit).  This will segment to visitors who were customers, which if compared to other e-commerce websites will be around 3% of your visitors.  You can then examine which pages have the most pageviews in this segment, which will be a list of your most valuable pages - those pages that eventually resulted in a visit to your "money" page.  Your homepage will feature most likely, but the interesting insights will be down the list.

But its all a lot easier if you have ecommerce / goal tracking set up, as then you can use the segments already setup as default.  I would generally recommend to implement this ASAP, through Google Tag Manager if possible to make it easy to tweak later.

Answer (score 2):

Build an advanced "sequence" type segment. Put the url of the page in question as the first step and the url of your conversion page as subsequent step. See to how many people that segment applies (and compare to other pages in the same way to get a baseline).

This is pretty much how GA attributes page value if you track revenue ( how many visits with conversions included this url) so it should work as one possible success indicator for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a very rough estimate: determine the average revenue per visitor.  Then the rough value per page would be the number of visitors that land on that page times the average revenue per visitor.

If you want better data, you will have to implement tracking that tells Google Analytics this information.  You would then get better data on a going forward basis. Here is [an article that tells you a bit about how to set up conversion goals in Google Analytics](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/a-beginners-guide-to-conversion-goals-in-google-analytics/42558/)